# How to add extra rows when inserting data (extra empty rows)

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using apache poi to write excel file. I fill in the data in the loop.

For example:

```
header_1|header_2|header3|header_4|header_5|header6
aaaaaaa1|bbbbbb_1|cccccc3|
aaaaaaa2|bbbbbb_2|cccccc3|
aaaaaaa3|bbbbbb_3|cccccc3|
aaaaaaa4|bbbbbb_4|cccccc3|
```

[now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF1MT.png)
It's work fine, but I need extra 2 rows for each inserted row.
I want something like this:

```
header_1|header_2|header3|header_4|header_5|header6
aaaaaaa1|bbbbbb_1|cccccc3|test1111|test2222|test333
                         |TestLLLL|TestXXXX|testBBB
                         |TestLLLL|TestXXXX|testBBB
aaaaaaa2|bbbbbb_2|cccccc3|test1111|test2222|test333
                         |TestLLLL|TestXXXX|testBBB
                         |TestLLLL|TestXXXX|testBBB
aaaaaaa3|bbbbbb_3|cccccc3|test1111|test2222|test333
                         |TestLLLL|TestXXXX|testBBB
                         |TestLLLL|TestXXXX|testBBB
aaaaaaa4|bbbbbb_4|cccccc3|test1111|test2222|test333
                         |TestLLLL|TestXXXX|testBBB
                         |TestLLLL|TestXXXX|testBBB
```

[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1wSC.png)
What should a loop look like?

```
   for(Data d: allData){
     Row row = sheet.createRow(++row);
     Cell c = row.createCell(0);
     c.setCellValue("something);
     Cell c1 = row.createCell(1);
     c1.setCellValue("something1)
     //etc..
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for(Data d: allData){
   Row row = sheet.createRow(++row);
   Cell c = row.createCell(0);
   c.setCellValue("something01");
   c = row.createCell(1);
   c.setCellValue("something02")
   //etc..

   // Add extra rows:
   row = sheet.createRow(++row);
   c = row.createCell(0);
   c.setCellValue("something11");
   c = row.createCell(1);
   c.setCellValue("something12")
   //etc..
}
```

Edit: if the first row and the two 'empty rows' should share the headers 1-3 (and you just want to reduce the redundancy) then you can do something like `sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAdress(rowFrom, rowTo, colFrom, colTo)` to merge the columns and rows together (but that makes the excel file unsortable)